# JavaScript でのセミコロン ; の位置について

Tags: javascript

現在学習しているJSの教材で以下の記述があります。

```
const user = ['田中太郎','佐藤一郎','山田次郎'];
const result = user.map( element => {
  return element + 'さん';
})
console.log(result);
```

１行目や５行目ではセミコロン(`;`)が最後に付いています。一方、３行目に関しては途中に付いています。これはどのようなルールに基づくのでしょうか。ルールが分からないので非常に覚えにくいと感じています。ググってもよく分からなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 3行目でも行末（つまり最後）にセミコロンが付いている気がするのですが、途中についているとはどういう意味か、もう少し詳しく教えていただけませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
 私が学習したこれまでの事例は、いずれもセミコロンが括弧（[ ], { }, ( )など）の後に付いていたので、括弧の後に付けるものと思っていました。そのため、4行目の括弧の後に付くものと想定していました。 原則、セミコロンは行末に付けることを教えていただきましたので納得できました。

Answer (score 3):

> const user = ['田中太郎','佐藤一郎','山田次郎'];

> return element + 'さん';

> console.log(result);

これはいずれも1つの「文」（statement）です。
文の末尾にはセミコロン`;`を付けます。

（JavaScriptにはこのセミコロンの自動挿入機能があり、実は付けなくてもほとんどの場合大丈夫なのですが、例外もあるので、私は必ず付ける派です）

> const result = user.map( element => {
> return element + 'さん';
> })

これ全体も1つの文なので、本当は3行目の`)`の後ろにもセミコロンが必要です。
しかし前記のとおり無くても自動挿入されるのでエラーにはならないです。

JavaScriptの構文は下記が入門者にはわかりやすいかなと思います。

[文と式 · JavaScript Primer #jsprimer](https://jsprimer.net/basic/statement-expression/)

Comment: 分かりやすく教えていただきありがとうございます。
行末には必ず付けるものなのですね。本来ならお示しいただいた記述の3行目（質問文の4行目）にも必要とのことで理解しました。
また、参考リンクも教えていただきありがとうございました。勉強させていただきます。